# Need to refresh page for router navigate to work again?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a button which redirects to a post creation page, but for some reason it only functions once. afterwards I have to refresh the page in order for it to work again.

Running Angular2 and I believe I've tried the whole thing with relative paths..

```js
  selectCreateData() {
    if (this.myView.link) {
      this.router.navigate([this.myView.link, 'create']);
    } else {
      this.createDataValue = {};
    }
  }
```

```html
<button (click)="selectCreateData()">Create new Post</button>
```

No errors in the console, logging `this.myView.link` returns the whole path after `localhost`. example: `/7f45c1b1-b0c4-4f2d-96fd-a786889fbae2/projects/2723ec7d-3d2b-41f3-b332-b2e384a8e03a/process/`

Comment: Angular will not navigate if you are already on the exact target url.

Comment: But I'm not, once I create a post I'm redirected again to that page which has the button. in other words, whenever I'm clicking the button, I wanna be redirected to the page I'm in + '/create'

Comment: never mind i miss-read

Comment: Can you please post the route configuration and also what is `this.myView`? can you please update some more code on this

Comment: @boloao Does your page actually navigate to another url before you are redirected back to the page you're on? HttpClient posts in between don't count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to route to the "same" route again you'll want to use a combination of `onSameUrlNavigation` and subscribing to Router Events.

## Step 1

> onSameUrlNavigation Define what the router should do if it receives a navigation request to the current URL. (see https://angular.io/api/router/Router#properties)

You'll apply this using the `ExtraOptions` parameter for your `.forRoot([routes], { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' }`

## Step 2

Listen for `NavigationEnd` in your component class(es):

```
export class Test1Component {

    public constructor(private router: Router) {

        this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {

            if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {

                console.log(`${ new Date().toString() }: test1 component routed to`);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

## Example:

See https://github.com/mateothegreat/ng-byexamples-routing-same for a complete working example.